# In Android Go, how can I change the camera app?

Tags: camera, android-go

In non-Go Android versions I can install camera apps (eg OpenCamera) and set as default camera app. Then, in my custom app I could select OpenCamera as the camera and take pictures from it.

I cannot found the way to do it in Android Go, i'm using a Nokia 2.3 with Android 11, the default camera app has no picture settings so I cannot lower the resolution, and so far I cannot set OpenCamera as my app camera then I'm stuck in high resolution photos but I need only minimal resolution for my app to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't seem there is a "clear defaults" for the camera app as there used to be, but some people have had luck by disabling the stock camera app completely (Settings > Apps > Camera > Disable). This way, the next time something wants to access the camera, they'll be prompted to pick a default.